# Call an Async method after aspx page has been fully rendered on the client side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-4

so here is the situation. I have an aspx page that shows some charts. The data comes from a MVC 4 Web Api Restful service. 
Each query to the service for a "chart" takes roughly 30(s). Instead of the user waiting 30 seconds for each chart (when user clicks a button), I would like to load and Render the entire blank page, then make some calls to the web service.

I'm just trying to avoid the user "feeling" like the page is hanging. I would rather show a loading symbol on the page while it loads.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should render your page without the charts then use AJAX to load the charts asynchronously.

you could also put a gif image (loading image) then when the ajax call finishes you replace the image with your chart